# Copying structure from pointer type variable to non pointer type variable

Tags: c

I am wondering,  why the below code does not generate core dump ?
In func(), i am copying something like this:

```
d = *p;
```

**Correct me if i am wrong.**

Does it copy the entire structure, or just copies the first 4 bytes only ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct ABCD
{
  char *ptr;
  int abcd;
  char *ptr1;
};


int func ( struct ABCD *p )
{
  struct ABCD d;
  d = *p;
  printf (" \n Inside func, and value : %d  and str is %s ", d.abcd, d.ptr1);

}

int main ()
{
  struct ABCD a;
  struct ABCD *ptr;
  ptr = &a;
  ptr->abcd = 10;
  ptr->ptr1 = malloc (10);
  strcpy ( ptr->ptr1, "HI" );


  func (ptr);
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to core-dump, rather than just copying?

Comment: *it copy the entire structure*

Comment: I am not sure while doing d=*p, does it copy the entire structure to variable 'd'. if not, then  accessing 'ptr1' could be an issue right?

Comment: Members all fields are copied. address is copied for the member of ptr1. It is to be shared for its contents.

Comment: `d = *p` meant `d.ptr=p->ptr;d.abcd=p->abcd;d.ptr1=p->ptr1;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is a pointer, and `*` is a pointer dereference operator, so `*p` is the struct `p` points to. Hence the assignment is perfectly legal

`d = *p` will copy the entire struct pointed by `p` to `d`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does it copy the internal data structure also ? that means p->ptr1, i mean not the content, but the address itself?

Comment: @Whoami: After the copy, the value of all *members* of `d` will equal those of `*p`.

Comment: I wanted to do reverse thing (**struct variable** to **struct pointer variable** ), this solved my problem `*p=d`